# How to properly marshal to String object containing CDATA sections

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, jaxb

I have this class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MyObject", propOrder = ["element"])
class MyObject {
    @XmlAnyElement
    var element: Element? = null
}
```

what I need to do is create an Element and put an xml string as a text node or cdata section so after marshalling MyObject to string it still looks like valid xml (may be in cdata or commented out). I tried:

```
fun main() {
    val documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
    val document = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument()

    val myElement = document.createElement("myTag")
    myElement.appendChild(document.createCDATASection("<xml><a>text</a>"))

    val myObject = MyObject().apply {
        element = myElement
    }

    val writer = StringWriter()
    JAXB.marshal(myObject, writer)
    println(writer.toString())
}
```

but this returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myObject>
    <myTag>&lt;xml&gt;&lt;a&gt;text&lt;/a&gt;</myTag>
</myObject>
```

what should I do to get :

```
<myObject>
    <myTag><xml><a>text</a></myTag>
</myObject>
```

I cannot modify/add annotations to `MyObject` class.

Comment: If the content is XML, why do you want to put it in as a string? Why not put it in as XML?

Comment: Great idea, thanks. Now I'm getting error "The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed", but I guess I can remove offending line from input, if it cannot be avoided somehow.